# Ruby - Invalid URI message

Tags: ruby, uri

I have a URI like this:

> https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=lc&chd=s:cEAELFJHHHKUju9uuXUc&chco=76A4FB&chls=2.0&chs=220x125&chxt=x,y&chxr=1,0,4&chxl=3:|Jan|Feb|Mar&chxs=2,0000dd,13,-1,t,FF0000&chxp=2,10,35,95&chxtc=1,5,15

And I try this:

```
require 'open-uri'
open "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=lc&chd=s:cEAELFJHHHKUju9uuXUc&chco=76A4FB&chls=2.0&chs=220x125&chxt=x,y&chxr=1,0,4&chxl=3:|Jan|Feb|Mar&chxs=2,0000dd,13,-1,t,FF0000&chxp=2,10,35,95&chxtc=1,5,15"
```

And I get the following message:

> URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?):

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pipes are causing your problem. They have to be [percent encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

You may work around this by

```
uri = "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=lc&chd=s:cEAELFJHHHKUju9uuXUc&chco=76A4FB&chls=2.0&chs=220x125&chxt=x,y&chxr=1,0,4&chxl=3:|Jan|Feb|Mar&chxs=2,0000dd,13,-1,t,FF0000&chxp=2,10,35,95&chxtc=1,5,15" 
uri.gsub!('|', '%7C')
open uri
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try url-encoding the string with `CGI::escape(str)` ?

Comment: Yes. If I do that, when I do open it thinks is a file and not a URL.